# How can you create a Virtual IP, or Port in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'd like to create the equivalent of an AWS VPC or Openstack Network in VirtualBox, such that an IP address is capable of using IPVS to load balance between machines.

This is a way, for me, to simulate more complex deployments of my distributed app in a real world SDN scenario.

*workarounds*

Since this questions lacks context, here are a few workarounds that may be suitable to my use case, which also shed light on the end requirement:

1) A lightweight VM using HAProxy

2) A lightweight VM that sets up IP tables rules for routing randomly (by %) to n distinct downstream addresses.

Comment: 3) Consider also docker

Comment: Have you managed the virtual network adapters? And as well the v. networks of VirtualBox? There are several types allowing different access like between VMs, between VM/Host, access to the internet... Machines can have up to 4 network adapters connected to different v. networks. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: You can even configure port forwarding in the extended network adapter settings per machine.

Comment: After setting up the virtual "physical" layer, you might be able to setup a layer 4 network switch in one of the guest systems. This question could be better placed on https://serverfault.com/